# Filtering by values in vectors using purrr

Tags: r, function, functional-programming

I want to write a function that accepts two arguments: a data.frame and a vector (here, called `id_var`).
Then it filters the data.frame by a value that is in `id_var` (eg. the first value in the vector), adds the resulting data.frame to a variable called `data_filt_by_var`.

If the number of rows in `data_filt_by_var` is bigger than one... It takes that same initial `data.frame`, filter by the same `id_var` value and select the distinct `end` (end is a the name of that is present in the data.frame), and get its number of rows. If the number of rows is `>= 1`, returns `1`, else `0`.

The problem is, it has to do this to each value in id_var. I cannot make this iteration work without using loops, which are not desirable.
I wrote the following function, but its not working.

```r
is_this_unique = function(data, id_var) {
  data_filt_by_var = nrow(data[data$id == id_var, ])

  if (data_filt_by_var >= 1) {
    if (nrow(data[data$id == id_var, ] %>% 
             distinct(full_address)) == 1) {
      return(1)
    }
  } else {
    return(0)
  }
}

sample_data = (tibble::tribble(~id, ~full_address,
          1,'abc',
          1,'bcd',
          1,'abc',
          2,'qaa',
          2,'xcv',
          2,'qaa'))

id_var = c(1,2)
```

I was hoping to use `map_dbl` in this function.

The expected output would be:

input:

```
>is_this_unique(sample_data, id_var)
```

desired output:

```
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

The first 0 is because the first `id` and `full_address` pair (`1` and `abc`) are not unique, and so on...

Comment: Can you add a sample input to the function `is_this_unique` and show expected output based on that?

Comment: What is `full_address`

Comment: @akrun ```full_address``` and ```end``` are the same thing. I'll fix that now. And add the example @Ronak Shah asked.

Comment: I think your output would be `0 1 0 0 1 0` by checking the values

Comment: @JohnP.S. can you please check my solution

Comment: @akrun Its working! I've already checked that as the solution to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function can be written in tidyverse without using any loops with `purrr`.  This seems to be `group_by` count the frequency after `filter`ing for the 'id's passed into the function.  In this case, we group by 'id', and the column that is needed (inside the curly-curly -`{{}}`), create a logical column by checking the number of rows (`n()`) equal to 1.  If we pass an 'idvar' that is not in the dataset, it would usually return `integer(0)`, which can be changed to 0 with a `if/else` condition at the end

```
library(dplyr)   
is_this_unique <- function(data, id_var, colNm) {
     out <-  data %>%
         filter(id %in% id_var) %>%
          group_by(id, {{colNm}}) %>%
          transmute(n = +(n() == 1)) %>%
          pull(n)
      if(length(out) > 0) out else 0


         }

is_this_unique(sample_data, 1:2, full_address)
#[1] 0 1 0 0 1 0

is_this_unique(sample_data, 1, full_address)
#[1] 0 1 0


is_this_unique(sample_data, 0, full_address)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: I'm not having the desired result. But I added a example desired ouput to the question, could you check it?

Comment: @JohnP.S.  Sorry, misssed the `%>%` after the `filter`.  Updated

Answer (score 2):

IMO using `purrr` here isn't suitable, you can try this function.

```
library(dplyr)  

is_this_unique <- function(data, id_var) {
   temp_data <- data %>% filter(id %in% id_var)
   if (nrow(temp_data) > 0) 
      temp_data %>% 
         add_count(id, full_address) %>%
         mutate(n = +(n == 1)) %>%
         pull(n)
   else return(0)
}

is_this_unique(sample_data, 1:2)
#[1] 0 1 0 0 1 0

is_this_unique(sample_data, 1)
#[1] 0 1 0

is_this_unique(sample_data, 0)
#[1] 0
```